# How to filter a string in a column with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark 3.0 I have strings in a column with this format:

`item1: KO, item2: OK, item3:OK, item4: KO, ...etc more items...`

and I would like to filter out the `KO`s elements in order to transform the string in something like:

`item1: KO, item2: OK, item3:OK, item4: KO` -> `item2: OK, item3:OK`

At the moment I am using `regexp_replace` but I would like to avoid heavy usage of regexp. Is there a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom `udf` that will split each string into separate items and will join back those that end with OK:

```py
def filter_items(items_str):
    return ', '.join(item for item in items.split(', ') if item.endswith('OK'))

filter_items_udf = udf(filter_items, StringType())
```

You can also do this using spark primitives alone:

```py
filtered_items = array_join(
  array_filter(
    split("items", ", "),
    lambda x: x.endswith("OK")),
  ", "
)
```

For a purist version, you could avoid the use of a lambda altogether with `explode`:

```py
item_col = "items"
other_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != item_col]

exploded_items = df.select(
  *other_cols,
  explode(split(item_col, ", ")).alias(item_col)
).filter(
  col(item_col).endswith('OK')
).groupby(
  *other_cols
).agg(
  concat_ws(", ", collect_list(item_col)).alias(item_col)
)
```

If you want to keep rows without any OK items, you'll need to join the result back to the original dataframe.

Comment: You can do it with builtin functions, without the need of udf. See [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split), [`contains`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html#pyspark.sql.Column.contains), [`array_join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_join.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_join) ([full list of functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#functions))

Comment: I prefer the second solution with `array_filter` but in PySpark 3.0 it does not exists.

Comment: @Randomize, consider accepting if this solves your question :)

Comment: I am looking through the list of functions to get something similar to the solution 2

Comment: There is nothing similar, you have to use the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
('item1: KO, item2: OK, item3: OK, item4: KO', ),
('item1: OK, item2: OK, item3: KO, item4: KO', )]

schema = StructType([StructField('message', StringType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

df = df.withColumn('message', F.trim(F.concat_ws(',', F.filter(F.split(F.col('message'), ','), lambda x: x.endswith('OK')))))
```

Comment: unfortunately there is not`F.filter` for my case available.